# A particle has $\overrightarrow{r}(0)=4m(\hspace{2pt}\hat{j}\hspace{2pt})$ and $\overrightarrow{v}(0)=(2m/s^2)\hat{i}$

Tags: particle-physics, kinematics, vectors

I am having trouble with these problems, and I want to gain a understanding of how to solve these. I'll put what I have tried at the end, even though I don't think it'll be of help. A particle has $\overrightarrow{r}(0)=4m(\hspace{2pt}\hat{j}\hspace{2pt})$ and $\overrightarrow{v}(0)=(2m/s)\hat{i}$.
If it's acceleration is constant and given by$\overrightarrow{a}-(2m/s^2)(\hspace{2pt}\hat{i}\hspace{2pt}+\hspace{2pt}\hat{j}\hspace{2pt})$, at what time $t$ does the particle first cross the x-axis? $$$$And a related question: At what time $t$ is the particle moving parallel to the y-axis, that is in the $\hat{j}$ direction?$$$$So what I did is draw a vector going up $4m$ because of the $4m\hat{j}$ and wrote down $a_y=-2m/s^2$ and $a_x=-2m/s^2$ and that is pretty much it. A complete explanation of how to solve this problem would be greatly appreciated, and sorry for not having much insight, i'm just really lost with this problem. Thanks for all the help in advance.

EDIT: My work for question 1 $$$$So for the first question I used $$\vec{x}_f=\vec{x}_i+\vec{v}_it+\frac{1}{2}\vec{a}t^2$$ and plugged in $$0=4m+2m/s(t)+\frac{1}{2}(-2m/s^2)t^2,$$ and ended with the quadratic function of 
$4+2t-t^2=0$ or $t^2-2t-4$ and found the roots at $t=1\pm \sqrt{5}$ but the answer was wrong. What did I do wrong? (I inputed both values) $$$$EDIT #2: I can't input any more times, so I cannot check my answer but I think I the answer is $2s$. In my first attempt I put $2m/s$ as the initial velocity, when it was actually 0. So I think the correct formula inputs are $0=4-t^2$ and therefore $t=2$, would that be right?

Comment: Hint: Newton's second law is a vector equation- apply it by i and j components.

Comment: These are the vector formulas we've been given, but I don't know how to apply them. http://i.stack.imgur.com/zSzlJ.png Any suggestions? @paisanco

Comment: Yes you figured it out - your initial vertical velocity is 0 and your acceleration is $2 m/s^2$. So you calculate the time to cover $4m$ and get the answer you obtained in your second edit.

Comment: @Floris thanks a lot for clarifying. I don't know why I felt this was much harder than it actually was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few basic formulas for solving this kind of stuff:

$$\vec{x}_f=\vec{x}_i+\vec{v}_it+\frac{1}{2}\vec{a}t^2,$$
$$\vec{v}_f=\vec{v}_i+at.$$

These are vector formulas, but all you're doing with the vectors is adding/subtracting them. When you add vectors you add the individual components, i.e.

$$\vec{a}=(a_1,a_2,a_3)$$
$$\vec{b}=(b_1,b_2,b_3)$$
$$\vec{a}+\vec{b} = (a_1+b_1, a_2+b_2, a_3+b_3).$$

So for your first question, you want to find what time your $r_y$ component is 0, as that is when the particle is on the x-axis. For your second question, your particle will be moving parallel to the y-axis when it's velocity is completely in the y direction, in other words your $v_x=0$.

Comment: So for the first question I used $$\vec{x}_f=\vec{x}_i+\vec{v}_it+\frac{1}{2}\vec{a}t^2$$ and plugged in $$0=4m+2m/s(t)+\frac{1}{2}(-2m/s^2)t^2,$$ and ended with the quadratic function of 
$4+2t-t^2=0$ or $t^2-2t-4$ and found the roots at $t=1\pm \sqrt{5}$ but the answer was wrong. What did I do wrong?